# Why jenkins start all pipeline even if there's no changes for that particular folders?

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I have microservice based application in Bitbucket. For all service need to deploy I'm using Jenkins pipelines. And each jenkinsfile is in root directory. Whenever a commit is pushed, all the pipeline starts even if there's no changes related to that particular build.

How to set the jenkins in such a way that it only trigger the pipeline of particular service where changes is made and pushed?